# "Automatic" vs "Automatic (Delayed start)"

Tags: windows-services, wix

When installing Windows services there are two options for automatically starting a Windows service on Windows startup. One is *Automatic*, and the other is *Automatic (Delayed start)*. What is the difference between these two in detail?

For example, if you're creating the installer with wixtoolset, the `ServiceConfig` element has the `DelayedAutoStart` attribute. How will that effect what happens when services are started at boot time?

WiX documentation: *[ServiceConfig Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceconfig.html)*

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how this is considered off topic considering the fact that http://wixtoolset.org/ gives you the ability to specify this and we allow questions about Wix.

Comment: I believe this should be migrated to superuser instead of being closed as off topic. I see there are duplicates of this in superuser as well

Comment: I got here looking for an answer for wix installer. This is absolutely on topic for programming as an installer is kinda relevant to programming.

Comment: Agreed with Smithers and PitLock.  If you look at the vote-ups for both the question and the answers on this and other "closed" subjects, it seems that some members are more interested in the letter of the law rather than the usefulness of the post, which is the whole idea behind sites like this.  Apparently, they don't realize that this particular question does, in fact, affect "programming".  At least they didn't take the post down.

Comment: I don't agree that this is off topic. This is very relevant to developers.

Comment: Rather than complain (however valid) please vote to reopen If you can. This is a good question.

Answer (score 538, accepted):

In short, services set to *Automatic* will start during the boot process, while services set to start as *Delayed* will start shortly after boot.

Starting your service *Delayed* improves the boot performance of your server and has security benefits which are outlined in [the article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221180925/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx) Adriano linked to in the comments.

**Update:** "shortly after boot" is actually 2 minutes after the last "automatic" service has started, by default.  This can be configured by a registry key, according to [Windows Internals](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VgjAQjsc6g8C&pg=PT580) and other sources ([3](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#SetDelayedStartTime),[4](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/delay-loading-of-specific-services-windows)).

The registry keys of interest (At least in some versions of windows) are:

- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>\DelayedAutostart` will have the value `1` if delayed, `0` if not.
- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AutoStartDelay` or `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\AutoStartDelay` (on Windows 10): (DWORD) decimal number of milliseconds to wait, may need to create this one. Applies globally to all *Delayed* services.

Comment: I'm wondering, how short is shortly? Not much information out there. It somehow looks like Windows would wait, until the system load drops, or a certain step during the boot sequence has been reached. After that it begins starting any delayed services. Any oppionions or even knowledge on that?

Comment: @leo 2 mins after the last automatic service - answer updated.

Comment: With multiple delayed start services, how does windows decide which to start first?

Comment: @ErnestSoeralaya services can be marked as dependent on other services. Windows will ensure the dependencies are started first, then after that the services *should* start in alphabetical order; but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: I wonder what happens if one of the "automatic" service was not started correctly (failed to start) to my service if I marked it as "automatic (delayed start)"

Comment: @MeM A failure in any one service will not affect any other service.  The only exception to this are services which are marked as dependent on other services.

Comment: Adding the registry hack to your answer would be nice.

Comment: According to Tom Wijsman on superuser.com the default delay of 120 seconds can be overridden by the `AutoStartDelay` value in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`. I haven't checked it.

Comment: So each service is started serially, one by one, or will it actually do multiple concurrent "starts" at a time?  ie, if you have multiple cores (which most people do these days)...

Comment: It would be nice to be able to stagger the startup or configure these little details.  I'd hate to be booted for 2 minutes just to have my  machine come to a crawl for a minute while it starts everything marked as "DELAYED".  Like a Third-Party Windows Service that handles startup of over Services... hmmm

Comment: According to the references 3 and 4 in this same answer, the last key should have been `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`