# My service does not automatically start

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I've got a problem with starting automatically my own C# service in win2k8.
Basically service it self monitors a folder in a loop for changes (since the file system limitations).
When I set service for autostart (or delayed start) it is in started state but does nothing. After that when I restart it manually everything starts working fine...

Here is my onStart method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  if (timer == null)
  {
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Interval = 1;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DoStuff);
  }
  eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
  timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: check the windows event log, see if there're errors

Comment: Do you ever see your event log entry? What does the timer do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015189/automatic-vs-automatic-delayed-start

Comment: Not really related but did you consider using FileSystemWatcher instead of looping through files in the folder? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Did you try to wide delay for at least 5 minutes?

Comment: Read the answer at the link I posted, it answers your question.  Delayed and automatic start are intended for use at boot, not after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015189/automatic-vs-automatic-delayed-start

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is very cool but it is not working on GPFS, thats why Iam watching folder for changes in a loop. Event log is clear.  Timer calls "DoStuff" every 60 sec. Here is a code at the end of DoStuff: TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastChecked);
TimeSpan MaxWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            if (MaxWaitTime.Subtract(ts).CompareTo(TimeSpan.Zero) > -1)
                timer.Interval = MaxWaitTime.Subtract(ts).TotalMilliseconds;
            else
                timer.Interval = 1;

            timer.Start();