# Elastic Kibana - install as windows service

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch

How can I install Elastic Kibana (which is just a batch file) as a windows service?

It probably needs to depend on the ElasticSearch process as well (this assumes I'm running it on the same server)

Comment: Use NSSM [link](https://nssm.cc/)

Comment: Maybe you should change the "correct answer" flag? It seems sc create does not work any more, but nssm still does.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The following command will create the service with a name of "ElasticSearch Kibana 4.0.1" and make it depend on ElasticSearch so it doesn't try to start too soon.

```
sc create "ElasticSearch Kibana 4.0.1" binPath= "{path to batch file}" depend= "elasticsearch-service-x64"
```

Comment: Please note that there should be a single whitespace after **binpath=** - it is required by sc utility cmd line format. Without whitespace, command is not valid and service is not created.

Comment: @Alexander the same is true for the "depend" parameter (and any other params you want to pass to sc.exe). They need to be formatted like [paramName]= "param value".

Comment: For some reason I couldn't just type the command in powershell. I had to first save as a `.bat` file and then execute.

Comment: If you're running in Powershell, replace "sc" with "sc.exe", i.e. sc.exe create ... (because sc is, by default, an alias for set-content in Powershell)

Comment: I've got a service now installed but it does not start. Any way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem - kibana starts and runs, but the service gives an error and is marked as 'not running' even though kibana is still running in the background.

Comment: I got this working using NSSM (None-Sucking-Service-Manager!)

Comment: Did anybody figured out how to get service status to display correctly?

Comment: `sc` did not work for me with Kibana 5.3.0, it started Kibana (node) but wasn't displaying it as started, I used `nssm` instead, see other answer.

Comment: Same here, installing via sc causes the process to be started but the service indicates an error when starting, i use nssm as described below.

Comment: SC is mean to be used with executables that support start and stop signals. So start a batch file as a service will fail in many situations, like a long warm up time or stopping the service. Using nssm tool to wrap the control of the batch file is a much better option.

Answer (score 52):

The kibana.bat file delivered with Kibana 4.6.1 was not suited to use with sc create directly for me (Service start failed).
I used [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) like this

1. `nssm install kibana461`
2. UI: choose `kibana.bat` as Application Path
3. UI: select a log file to write to on "I/O" tab for stdout and stderr
4. UI: on the "Dependencies" tab enter `elasticsearch241` (or whatever you called it)
5. UI: "Install Service"
6. `sc start kibana461`

Comment: I had the same problem using just "sc" from the accepted answer. Using NSSM as described here worked for me

Comment: server2016, kibana 5.3.4. Didn't work with sc. Works with nssm. Doesn't suck at all!

Comment: Worked like a charm, so thank you for that. Although you will need to create the log-files specified in the I/O tab. Empty files will do. If not, service will not start.

Comment: I think only the folder needs to exist. I've never created any files.

Answer (score 14):

Rather than creating a dependency, I made a delayed start.

1. First use the `sc` command (from jhilden).

   ```
   sc create "Elasticsearch Kibana 4.4.2" binPath= "C:\kibana-4.4.2-windows\bin\kibana.bat"
   ```
2. Open `services.msc` and find your new service.
3. Right click the service and select `Properties`.
4. Change to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`.
5. If you haven't already, change Elasticsearch to `Automatic`.

[image: services]

This will ensure elasticsearch will start when the machine starts, and kibana will start sometime soon after (approx 2 minutes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11015189/266535)).

Comment: What advantage does this have over the dependency?

Comment: I linked to a related question in my answer. The relevant part: "Services set to Automatic will start during the boot process, while services set to start as Delayed will start shortly after boot." In my case, I want Elasticsearch to be up as soon as the server comes up and dedicate all resources to it, then we can start Kibana and dedicate resources after boot.

Comment: I am following this approach for Kibana 7.6.2 but I get this error message: "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I found this video very helpful.

Use NSSM (Non-sucking Service Manager) to install Kibana as a Service.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-0A2cqTn-w