# Problems creating Kibana Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, kibana-4

I registered the Kibana binary as a service [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261810).

When I try to start the service, I get the following error message:
[image: Windows could not start the Kibana service on Local Computer. The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.]

However, when I try to access http://localhost:5602 in the browser, Kibana is loaded properly. But the service is still listed as "Stopped".

So it seems like the Kibana binaries are executed but the Windows Service doesn't know how to interprete the status?
Any ideas on this?

Comment: I get this too but everything starts up properly.  If someone has a workaround I'd love to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot just install a Windows service using a .bat file.

Take a look at this question & answer for a workaround: https://serverfault.com/a/56472/101433