# How can I install and execute Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to install Elasticsearch.I downloaded this and I need to activate Elasticsearch.Actually,in command prompt,I executed this line in bin directory:

```
bin/elasticsearch.bat
```

As follows,I added screenshot of the command prompt.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxZmkxB6kqAkdmt2MHRtOWJreTg

While commant prompt is open,this site executes.http://localhost:9200/

But when I closed command prompt,this site is not execute.

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261810/1173800

Comment: But,I just  want to install Elasticsearch.I will install Kibana later.My problem is to activate Elasticsearch.

Answer (score -1):

Instructions to install ES on windows can be found here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/zip-windows.html#windows-service